# How to handle XPC connection interrupted in URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: swift, xcode

This is my code, by which I am trying to catch the error, when server is down:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please check yourr internet connection.")
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    if parseJSON["errorMessageKey"] != nil
                    {
                        self.displayMessage(userMessage: parseJSON["errorMessage"] as! String)
                        return
                    }                        
                    ...  

                } else {
                    self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
                }

            } catch {
                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
                print(error)
            }
        }
task.resume()
```

But in console I get "XPC connection error", instead of displaying alert.

How can I display Alert, when this error occures?

My environment:

Swift: 5

Xcode: 11.5

Target deployment: 13.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `displayMessage` has no problem as you have not provided the code.

I would suggest you call the code which has the UIKit API, on the main thread. As the `dataTask` completion block is always called on a background thread. I would suggest you while calling the function which further has the code related to UIKit should always run on the main thread

> Use **UIKit** classes only from your app’s **main thread** or **main dispatch**
>   queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction particularly
>   applies to classes derived from **UIResponder** or that involve
>   manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

Have a look at the updated code snippet.

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
       // It ensure rest code placed inside run on the main thread. I assume displayMessage function having the code related to UIKit framework.
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           if error != nil
           {
               self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please check yourr internet connection.")
               print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
               return
           }

           do {
               let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

               if let parseJSON = json {
                   if parseJSON["errorMessageKey"] != nil
                   {
                       self.displayMessage(userMessage: parseJSON["errorMessage"] as! String)
                       return
                   }

               } else {
                   self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
               }

           } catch {
               self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
               print(error)
           }
       }
   }
  task.resume()
```